# MySQL importing data fails but storage shrinks

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a sql dataset into mysql for my final year project,
the dataset is this one: https://github.com/SOLAR-group/TAWOS

the database is large (~4Gb), the import fails for some reason.

i used MySQL Workbench and the command line client

but even though the import fails and i drop the database so that i can try again, i noticed that my storage space is getting less every time i try to import. and that worries me now more than figuring out why the import fails.

how can i free up that space?

Edit: to be clear i am not trying to free up space from single tables, i have already dropped the whole database and the storage space available in C: keeps getting smaller.

Comment: Use `TRUNCATE tablename` to clear all its space.